# closing jquery colorbox modal window when clicking specific button which exists in the content came from external link

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a jquery colorbox application.In this application,When i click a link,a jquery colorbox modal box opens and it contents come from external link.There is a button inside of the content and i want to close colorbox window when i click that button.Is there any way to close colorbox modal window?There is colorbox's own closing button but i dont want to use that because my application needs a button in order to close it.
I used `$.fn.colorbox.close();` when click button but it didn't work.
Thanks for advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try attaching a jQuery live event to the button. Assuming you add a button with class `closebutton` to the color box content:

```
$('#cboxContent .closebutton').live('click', function(){
 $.fn.colorbox.close();
});
```

Comment: It should be added to the main page, not the external content page. External content javascript is automatically disabled by jQuery.